# Understanding the basic Laplace Transform?

Tags: calculus

[How has the author arrived at eq 3.3 from eq 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJi3i.png)

[My solution - Incomplete?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGqR5.png)

As can be seen i can get a part of the right hand side of the equation from basic algebraic manipulation, however i can't see how the rest of the equation has been worked out. I am assuming that the error lies somewhere in my assumption that the Laplace Transform of the right hand side of eq 3.2. is 1/s.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $3.2$, we have

$$\tag 1 I(s) = \dfrac{s L i(0) + 1}{s(L s + R)} = \dfrac{s i(0) + \dfrac{1}{L}}{s\left(s + \dfrac{R}{L}\right)} = \dfrac{s~ a + b}{s(s + c)}$$

Note that I am using the temporary variable names:

$$a = i(0), b = \dfrac{1}{L}, c = \dfrac{R}{L}$$

Doing a [*partial fraction decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $(1)$, we have

$$\tag 2 \dfrac{s a + b}{s(s + c)} = \dfrac{a}{s + c} + \dfrac{b}{c s} - \dfrac{b}{c(s + c)}$$

Substituting back the original variables, we have

$$\tag 3\dfrac{i(0)}{s + \dfrac{R}{L}} + \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{L}}{s \dfrac{R}{L}}-\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{L}}{\dfrac{R}{L}\left(s + \dfrac{R}{L}\right)} = \dfrac{i(0)}{s + \dfrac{R}{L}} + \dfrac{1}{Rs} - \dfrac{1}{R\left(s + \dfrac{R}{L}\right)}$$

Now, we just collect the like terms and arrive at $3.3$ as

$$\dfrac{i(0)}{s + \dfrac{R}{L}} + \dfrac{1}{Rs} - \dfrac{1}{R\left(s + \dfrac{R}{L}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{R}\left(\dfrac{1}{s} - \dfrac{1}{s + \dfrac{R}{L}}\right)+ \dfrac{i(0)}{s + \dfrac{R}{L}}$$